# Recursive type parameters in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to write something like that in Kotlin.

```
open class View<P> where P:Presenter<out _this_class_> {
    val presenter: P = ...
}

open class Presenter<V> where V: View<out _this_class_> {
    val view: V = ...
}
```

How I can properly do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way (called [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)) is

```
open class View<V: View<V, P>, P: Presenter<out V>> { ... }
```

It may make more sense to put `out` elsewhere here, depending on the specifics:

```
open class View<out V: View<V, P>, out P: Presenter<V>> { ... }
```