# How to solve 2nd level inheritance with generic classes?

Tags: android, generics, inheritance, kotlin, polymorphism

I'm implementing an MVP architecture in `Kotlin` and Android Studio shows no error, however it doesn't compile:

> java.lang.AssertionError: resultingDescriptor shouldn't be null:
>   candidateDescriptor: constructor BasePresenter(view:
>   View) defined in com.exmaple.base.BasePresenter substitution:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.IndexedParametersSubstitution@70144d7e     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.model.ResolvedCallImpl.setResultingSubstitutor(ResolvedCallImpl.java:205)
>     ....

Is it possible to use the `ConcreteView` / `ConcretePresenter` in the middle of inheritance?

code:

```
/**
 * These are the base classes
 */
interface MvpView

interface BaseView<Presenter : BasePresenter<*>> : MvpView, HasMvpView<MvpView>

// to avoid circular dependency
interface HasMvpView<View : MvpView> 

abstract class BaseMvpActivity<Presenter : BasePresenter<*>> : AppCompatActivity(), HasMvpView<MvpView>

abstract class BaseMvpFragment<Activity : BaseMvpActivity<*>, Presenter : BasePresenter<*>>: Fragment(), HasMvpView<MvpView> {
        // this will cause the error
        abstract var presenter: Presenter
}


/**
 * There's a Viewpager, and each page looks the same the only difference is their source of data. That's why I tried implementing another level of abstraction over the base classes
 */
interface CategoryPagerView<Presenter: BasePresenter<*>> : BaseView<Presenter>

abstract class CategoryPagerFragment: BaseMvpFragment<LandingActivity, BasePresenter<*>>()

/**
 * A concrete type of the Viewpager's fragment, its presenter and the view
 */
interface ConcreteView : CategoryPagerView<ConcretePresenter> 

class ConcretePresenter(view: ConcreteView) : BasePresenter<*>(view)

class ConcreteFragment : CategoryPagerFragment(), ConcreteView {
        // this line shows no error in the IDE, but in compile time
        override var presenter = ConcretePresenter(this)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you share the `BasePresenter` class? (or a minimal version of it) ?

Comment: same for `LandingActivity`.  all classes are needed.

Comment: sure! https://pastebin.com/YtELkQ0p

Comment: sorry, forgot the activity: https://pastebin.com/WesnxeCb

Comment: I suspect the compiler bug is triggered by the use of `*` as type parameter.  You may want to avoid this anyway.  I think you want the `BaseView`'s `Presenter` parameter to be bound to the concrete type of the `BaseView` itself), right?

Comment: You can do that similar to the way it's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304981/775138), which also happens to be about Views and Presenters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an internal assertion error thrown by the compiler.  You can see the compiler source code where this is thrown:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/calls/model/ResolvedCallImpl.java

Apparently the `resultingDescriptor` is `null` at a point where it should never be `null`.  So it seems like a compiler bug.  Maybe it should be rewritten in Kotlin to avoid issues with `null` :)

Please file a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT